# Запись результатов xpath в массив

Tags: c#, xpath

Подскажите пож-ста, как можно в массив записать все результаты xpath'a ?

У меня есть XML следующего вида:

```
<cspr:CharacteristicValueList>
    <cspr:name>member</cspr:name>
    <cspr:CharacteristicValue>
        <gen:name>id</gen:name>
        <gen:value>sip:+00112233111@qwerty.qq</gen:value>
    </cspr:CharacteristicValue>
</cspr:CharacteristicValueList>
<cspr:CharacteristicValueList>
    <cspr:name>member</cspr:name>
    <cspr:CharacteristicValue>
        <gen:name>id</gen:name>
        <gen:value>sip:+00112233222@qwerty.qq</gen:value>
    </cspr:CharacteristicValue>
</cspr:CharacteristicValueList>
<cspr:CharacteristicValueList>
    <cspr:name>member</cspr:name>
    <cspr:CharacteristicValue>
        <gen:name>id</gen:name>
        <gen:value>sip:+00112233333@qwerty.qq</gen:value>
    </cspr:CharacteristicValue>
</cspr:CharacteristicValueList>
```

Я хочу вытащить все 3 значения из **gen:value**
Для этого я написал Xpath, который находит все эти значения, но не пойму, как вывести их все. Ниже мой код + Xpath, который находит все 3 значения, однако код выводит только первое значение: **sip:+00112233111@qwerty.qq**
Как можно получить все значения ? В XML их может быть сколько угодно.
Думал сделать циклом (While), но получаю ошибку **Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.**

```
string act = "/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*/csp:compositeService/cspr:serviceSpecificationContainer/*/cspr:name[text() = 'account-cac']/../*/*/cspr:name[text() = 'member']/../*/gen:value";

if (nav.SelectSingleNode(act, nsmgr) != null)
{
    XPathNavigator acts = nav.SelectSingleNode(act, nsmgr);
    account_cac = acts.Value;
}
```

Xpath выдает 3 значения:

```
sip:+00112233111@qwerty.qq
sip:+00112233222@qwerty.qq
sip:+00112233333@qwerty.qq
```

Требуется поместить их в один массив, либо сразу в строку.

```
result = string.Join("|", account_cac_array);
```

Comment: описал подробнее.

Comment: Вместо `SelectSingleNode` нужно использовать `SelectNodes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У [`XPathNavigator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator(v=vs.110).aspx) существуют методы `Select` позволяющие выбрать набор узлов с помощью заданного выражения. Они возвращают итератор [`XPathNodeIterator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator(v=vs.110).aspx).

Вы можете обрабатывать результаты в привычном вам цикле `foreach` (или `while`), но можно воспользоваться методом `OfType`.

Таким образом для получения массива вам нужен примерно следующий код:

```
        string[] arr = nav.Select(act, nsmgr)
            .OfType<XPathNavigator>()
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .ToArray();
```